# Delphi unit gets ignored while compiling component

Tags: delphi, compiler-errors, delphi-2010

I'm trying to compile TBX_D2010 on Delphi 2010. Compile fails with E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'TTBPopupPositionRec' in TBX.pas.

The weird thing is that TTBPopupPositionRec is declared in unit TB2Item. Even weirder is that I can edit TB2Item.pas, even delete the whole content and it still would fail with the same error, ignoring the errors introduced in TB2Item.pas, as if it would be using some other, different copy of TB2Item. However, removing TB2Item from uses of TBX.pas fails with a different error.

I've dir /s for TB2Item.* and found nothing suspicious, and deleted all TB2Item.dcu files.

What's going on, why is Delphi ignoring my changes in TB2Item.pas?

Comment: Do you have a package installed that contains this unit?

Comment: Thanks, that lead me on the right way. I removed all .bpl and .dcp files of the other package, recompiled, reinstalled the other package and the new one and everything worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting the answer so I can close this:

I removed all .bpl and .dcp files of the other package, recompiled, reinstalled the other package and the new one and everything worked.

Answer (score 4):

[TBX](http://code.google.com/p/tbxlib/) is the an add-on for [Toolbar 2000](http://www.jrsoftware.org/tb2kdl.php).

By default TB2Item.pas does not contain `TTBPopupPositionRec` this is added by running the the diff's found in `TBX\Tools\TB2k Patch\` directory.

Not having this type found would indicate the patch has not been applied correctly.

Another note is that I have noticed that Toolbar 2000 last supported version was Delphi 2009.
Since your compiling with Delphi 2010 it possible you have one or more compiler defines that need to be updated.

Comment: The problem was that I installed unpatched TB2K, then removed it to patch it but without deleting bpl and dcp files the removal wasn't complete.

Answer (score 2):

This typically happens when you have a package installed in the IDE that includes the mysterious unit that cannot be located.

Exactly what the solution is depends on your precise scenario.